# error in plugin does not get any result

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

i want to add some style in plugin it is possible to add ?
like this 
i created a plugin and try to all image border automatic after plugin active. but not working it is possible how to solve this.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register22');    
function portfolio_register22() {   ?>
<style>
.img
{
border: 4px solid #FFF;
position: relative;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888;
border-radius: 55px;
}
</style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: that is because you are using a class named `.imag` try with the DOM element

Comment: thanx @co0lk3ek please tell me in details if possible

Comment: i would not do it like that, i would create a css file, and use `wp_enqueue_style` and that css will use `img` but without the `position` and in that plugin init function just the line for the adding the css to the DOM file, good luck

Comment: i know that i can create or use `wp_enqueur_style` but i want to direct use of style.

Comment: I don't see a point in creating another browser request for one style. And one that is almost certainly going to be used on every page. Boopathi's code below will do that you need, but if you want it to cover all images change `.img` to `img`.

Answer (score 0):

add these following code in your plugin and try it

```
<?php
    // Add css to wp_head()
    function child_head_styles() {
        ?>
    <style>
    .img
    {
     border: 4px solid #FFF;
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 4px;
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888;
     border-radius: 55px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'child_head_styles' );
?>
```